# Consulta con null en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Tengo una tabla *ventas_pedidos* en esta tabla tengo 3 campos importantes:

- vivienda(numerico)
- estado(enum)
- estado_envio(enum)

Necesito hacer una consulta que me filtre por el estado cuando sea activo y que el campo *vivienda* sea distinto de cero, pero que los `null` los devuelva, es decir, para aclarar un poco la consulta sería algo así:

```php
$venta=venta_pedidos::where('estado','aceptado')->where('vivenda','!=',0)->where('estado_envio','pendiente')->get();
```

Pero con esto no me devuelve los `null` del campo vivienda y si le meto la función `orWhereNull()` utiliza todos los `null` sin excepción, no mira el estado en el que están.

Comment: Pero que campo se supone que tiene null?

Comment: El campo de vivienda

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) la respuesta que te ha sido más útil (o aceptar la tuya cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo).

Comment: Poner una respuesta que no te ha servido, y tu mismo has dicho que no te ha servido, es un problema debido a que otros que vengan con tu problema usaran esa respuesta y no funciona... si no te ha servido no la marques como respuesta aceptada... y por la tuya almenos...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que algo así te podría servir:

```php
$venta = venta_pedidos::where('estado','aceptado')
    ->where('estado_envio','pendiente')
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('vivenda', '<>', '0')
            ->orWhereNull('vivenda');
    })
    ->get();
```

si no me equivoco esto generara una `SQL` parecida a esta:

```sql
SELECT * FROM venta_pedidos WHERE estado = 'aceptado' AND estado_envio = 'pendiente' AND (vivienda <> 0 OR vivienda IS NULL);
```

Cogiendo todos los que tengan *estado* = aceptado, *estado_envio* = pendiente y *vivienda* diferente de 0 o que sea NULL

Answer (score 0):

En vivenda tienes que indicarle el campo que quieres que mire en este caso vivienda:

```
$venta = venta_pedidos::where('estado','aceptado')->where('vivenda','!='0)->where('estado_envio','pendiente')->orWhereNull('vivenda')->get();
```

Eso lo he probado ayer en un proyecto y ha funcionado, eso debería de servirte.

Echále un ojo a las [consultas avanzadas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#advanced-where-clauses) de laravel.

Comment: No termina de funcionar, el problema es el ultimo orWhereNull, si le pones esa clausula da igual en el estado en el que esta que si esta nulo zasca entra, pero muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Lo tengo resuelto:

Era un tontería resulta que no estaba teniendo en cuenta que si pones la clausula orWhere() tienes que volver a especificar las condiciones restrictivas entonces con volver a repetir lo de lo estados y actualizar la clausula ya valdría se quedaría así:

```php
$venta=venta_pedidos::where([['estado','aceptado'],['vivenda','!=',0],['estado_envio','pendiente']])->orWhere(['estado','aceptado'],['vivenda',null],['estado_envio','pendiente'])->get();
```